# StructureMap and MVC 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tdd, asp.net-mvc-3, structuremap, ioc-container

Has anyone used structuremap with the new DI features of asp.net mvc 3.0?  If so, could you post some example code or some links to examples that have been helpful?  In attempting to learn ASP.NET MVC 3, I am trying to make sure I use all the "new" features and am struggling with integrating a IoC container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others mentioned you'd want to look at [Common Service Locator](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/) (CSL) that is a simple service resolution facade around any container (any of your choice).

MVC3 internally heavily uses the new [IDependencyResolver](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/service-location-pt5-idependencyresolver.html) interface which is somewhat like CSL but in ASP.NET MVC context. The good thing is that if you are already using CSL then you can set it **as** Dependency Resolver for MVC.

This topic is equally essential for any container and not specific to StructureMap.

So what is going on there:

- You provide all necessary container registrations (preferrably through Registry DSL in case of StructureMap);
- You get the [StructureMap adapter](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=StructureMap%20Adapter) for Common Service Locator;
- You (optionally - if you need CSL along with DependencyResolver) register your StructureMap adapter as current Service Locator:
  `ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => yourStructureMapAdapter)`
- You register your CSL (backed by StructureMap) as MVC DependencyResolver:
  `DependencyResolver.SetResolver(yourStructureMapAdapter)`
- MVC3 automatically wires everything up through [IDependencyResolver](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/service-location-pt5-idependencyresolver.html) interface internally (using all StrucutreMap DI auto-wiring capabilities).

Along with MVC3 baked-in IoC capabilities, use the power of IoC tool at your disposal (e.g. use Assemblies scanning available in StructureMap) to max extent.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I ran into this (http://codingndesign.com/blog/?p=164) tutorial/article as well...it was really helpful.  I'm going to try to put together what I did to implement it and share it here.  I haven't quite worked out all the bugs, but its coming!  :)

Answer (score 1):

I looked around a bit and this is the first Google result I got. It gives a good of what is new in MVC 3 service location: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/service-location-pt1-introduction.html

While it is dependent on a beta version of MVC 3, I am sure with some experimentation one can figure it out.

In a nutshell, it looks like they added some interfaces and extension methods that you can use to call StructureMap, or whatever your preferred IoC library is.

**Update:**

I just happened upon this link in the blogs I subscribe to. It has some good-looking sample code.
http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/how-do-i-use-structuremap-with-asp-net-mvc-3/

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this the other day, may be helpful:

http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/02/15/asp-net-mvc-unity-and-common-service-locator.aspx

Comment: I looked at that one.  It was the example I saved as the best starting point.  Thanks for that one.  I agree.  It is helpful.